# Can't read file in Xcode - Using C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, visual-c++, stream

Am using OSx(Capitan)'s Xcode to code my C++ projects. I am trying Xcode to code C++ for the first time (Not that familiar with C++ also).I have a C++ project named registration, all my Cpp and Header files are inside this directory. I need to read from a file named `rinput.txt` and output it to a new file named `routput.txt`. I have tried Visual Studio and it worked perfectly fine for me. Is there anything special I need to do in Xcode? I have already put my `rinput.txt` in my main directory(where all my cpp and header files resides). What should I need to do to make it work? Guys any idea?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "course.h"  
#include "regist.h"  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream infile( "rinput.txt" );
  if( !infile ) return -1;

  Registration R;
  infile >> R;

  ofstream ofile( "routput.txt" );

  ofile << R
    << "Number of courses = " << R.GetCount() << '\n'
    << "Total credits     = " << R.GetCredits() << '\n';

  // Declare and initialize a Course, and modify
  // its credits.

  Course aCourse( "MTH_3020", 'B', 2 );
  aCourse.SetCredits( 5 );
  cout << aCourse << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a minimal example of the relevant code in your question?

Comment: Did you try specifying the full path of the file? It's likely, that the program isn't running under your main project source directory.

Comment: @ajshort: Oh sorry I can include my codes.

Comment: Yes navta pei, I tried like this:
`int main()
{
  ifstream infile( "Users/Gentle/Documents/Cpp_Excerciese/registration/rinput.txt" );
  if( !infile ) return -1;
  Registration R;
  infile >> R;
  ofstream ofile( "/Users/Gentle/Documents/Cpp_Excerciese/registration/routput.txt" );`
But no output file..